# Ember addon namespace not resolving

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a simple Ember-CLI addon which provides a few helper Mixins. This addon is meant to be consumed by a set of addons which all want to do user-interface things (react to size changes, field validation, etc.).

So in essence there is a three step chain:

1. **Ember CLI Application** consumes UI Ember Addon
2. **UI Addon** consumes Mixin Addon to gain access to a common features library
3. **Mixin Addon** provides a set of *Mixins* to consumers

If I put the *Mixins* implementation into the `/app/mixins` directory than the **UI Addon** can import these mixins with an import to `../mixins/[mixin-name]`. That works but when I try and move back to the actual Ember App it can no longer resolve the mixins.

I guess that's not surprising really and what I want to be able to do instead is reference the mixins directly, like so: `ui-mixin-library/mixins/[mixin-name]`. Unfortunately the resolver is not able to resolve this.

In order to help achieve this goal I have put all the mixins into the `/addon/mixins` directory -- and as the Ember-CLI page suggests -- I import and then export these in the corresponding `/app/mixins` folder. Doesn't seem to help. Not sure if maybe I need to run these mixins through `app.import`?

---

For reference purposes, the **Mixin Addon** can be found here: [addon on github](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-mixin-helpers/tree/32a7b22c856b720ae8bfa79b73cded7fe13ca461)

Comment: I did not find 'ui-mixin-library' anywhere. Have you tried 'ui-mixin-helpers/mixins/[mixin-name]'

Comment: Just tried this and it seems to be imported correctly import correction from 'ui-mixin-helpers/mixins/input-correction';

Comment: @blessenm where were you trying to import? In my test cases *within* `ui-mixin-helpers` the import seems to work but it's when I install the addon into something like [`ui-number-input`](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-number-input/tree/cd5f21be7a28e52f6e63c65d120288d22609b221) where the import starts to break.

Comment: I just created a new app and installed ur addon and tried to import in the app.js. But I see that you are having an addon that depends on another addon. I haven't really tried that. Let me see if I can find whats wrong.

Comment: also be sure to use commit version I linked to in the above comment as I've had to temporarily copy the mixins back into `ui-number-input` to get working.

Comment: I see that this is working in ur code 'import InputCorrectionMixin from '../mixins/input-correction';' ui-mixin-helpers does not seem to be there when I enter require.entries in console.

Comment: Yup. It has to do with CLI's custom resolver I believe. When an addon has a class definition in the `app/mixins` folder then the consuming application access it in it's own namespace. That's useful often for components (as no import statement is needed in templates) but not great for mixins. It definitely fails when you have an addon which uses an addon. In these cases you need the mixins/components/etc defined in the `addon/mixins` directory. This then puts it into it's own namespace.

Comment: note, this is why in the Ember CLI documentation it suggests you should put the implementation into the `addon/` directory and then in the `app/` directory you should just import it and then re-export it. This approach, however, has not worked for me. Not sure why.